# why pointer variable inside private class can't point to outside variable of class

Tags: c++, object, oop, pointers, shared-ptr

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Human
{
    private:
        int *age;
        string *name;
    
    public:
        Human(string p_name, int value)
        {
            
            *name = p_name;
            *age = value; 
            cout <<"Name of Person is "<<*name <<" and age is "<<*age<<endl;
        }

        ~Human()
        {
            delete name;
            delete age;

            cout<<"Destructor release all memory So now name is "<<*name << " and age is "<<*age<<endl;
        }

        void display()
        {
            cout << "The name is "<<*name <<" and age is "<<*age<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    int age = 24;
    string name = "CODY";
    Human cody(name,age);
    cody.display();
}
```

It is not printing anything.... What is happening can somebody explain it please.... Is it due to I implemented pointer variable incorrectly...Why is it incorrect please tell me then and what will be the alternative solution

Comment: You never allocate any space for the member variables `int *age; string *name;` so `*name = p_name; *age = value; ` is UB.

Comment: Instead of `*age = value` it should be `age = new int(value)`.

Comment: First you need to make sure that the data members `age` and `name` point to some variables of appropriate type. Then only you can dereference them. So, you have **undefined behavior** in your current program.

Comment: As an exercise, try writing your program without pointers.  If you need to change the caller's variables, pass by reference.

Comment: Pointers are evil, they can point to *anywhere*, including nowhere and places that don't have memory.  Difficult to validate a pointer.  Prefer not to use pointers unless absolutely necessary; then use a *smart* pointer.

Comment: Looking at your program, to be honest, it looks like you are not following your reputable C++ book when it comes to understanding pointers and dynamically allocated memory, and instead you are "doing your own thing".  If this is the case, remember that C++ is one of the most difficult computer languages to learn -- going by "feel" or "winging it" is not a good way to learn such a language.

Comment: Also, you tagged `shared-ptr`, and there are no `std::shared_ptr` or equivalent in any of the code you posted.  Also, your destructor invokes undefined behavior, even if you dynamically allocated those values.  `cout<<"Destructor release all memory So now name is "<<*name << " and age is "<<*age<<endl;` -- it is undefined behavior to dereference the pointer that you just called `delete` on.

Comment: The first hint that things are off the rails in your code is the lack of pairing of `delete` operators with no apparent `new` operators. You cannot `delete` something that wasn't `new`d in some form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why pointer variable inside private class can't point to outside variable of class

The premise of your question is faulty. A private member variable **can** point to outside of the class.

> ```
>     Human(string p_name, int value)
>     {
>         
>         *name = p_name;
>         *age = value;
> ```

You didn't initialise the pointers, so indirecting through them results in undefined behaviour. Don't do this.

> ```
> cout << "The name is "<<*name <<" and age is "<<*age<<endl;
> ```

Here, you indirect through the invalid pointers and the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> ```
>         delete name;
>         delete age;
>
>         cout<<"Destructor release all memory So now name is "<<*name << " and age is "<<*age<<endl;
> ```

Even if the pointers weren't invalid, it would be wrong to delete them. You didn't create any objects with allocating `new`, so there is nothing to delete. Deleting the pointers that weren't returned by allocating `new` will result in undefined behaviour. Don't do this.

Furthermore, even if `delete` had been valid, that would invalidate the pointers, and the successive indirection through the newly invalidated pointers in the `cout` statement would result in undefined behaviour. Don't do this either.

Solution: Remove the `delete` lines.

---

A solution where the class points to variables outside of the class: In order to refer to an object outside of a function, you need to use indirection. You can use a pointer parameters for example, and initialise the members to point to the same objects:

```
Human(string* p_name, int* value)
    : name(p_name), age(value)
    {}

// example usage:
Human cody(&name, &age);
```

Note that storing pointers in members is precarious because you must be aware of the relative lifetimes of the pointed objects, and the object containing the pointers. You must be sure that the pointers don't outlive the pointed objects.

Considering the problems of the referential design of your class, I urge you to consider using values instead. This would likely be more useful class in general:

```
struct Human {
    std::string name;
    int age;

    void display()
    {
        std::cout
            << "The name is "
            << name
            << " and age is "
            << age
            << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    Human cody {
        .name="CODY",
        .age=24,
    };
    cody.display();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake......

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your given program as explained below.

##### Mistake 1

**First** you need to make sure that the data members `age` and `name` point to some variables of appropriate type. Then only you can dereference them. Since you're dereferencing the pointers that don't point to objects of appropritate types, you have **undefined behavior** in your program.

```
Human(string p_name, int value)
        {
            
            *name = p_name; //Undefined behavior because name doesn't point to an std::string object
            *age = value; //Undefined behavior because age doesn't point to an int object
            cout <<"Name of Person is "<<*name <<" and age is "<<*age<<endl;
        }
```

##### Mistake 2

**Second** you can use `delete` when you have allocated memory using `new`. And since you have not allocated any memory using `new`, it is incorrect to use `delete`.

```
~Human()
        {
            delete name; //not valid 
            delete age;  //not valid

            cout<<"Destructor release all memory So now name is "<<*name << " and age is "<<*age<<endl; //undefined behavior as explained in mistake 3
        }
```

##### Mistake 3

**Third** you're dereferencing the pointers `age` and `name` just after you used `delete` on them. This again leads to **undefined behavior**.

```
cout<<"Destructor release all memory So now name is "<<*name << " and age is "<<*age<<endl; //undefined behavior because you just used `delete` on the pointers and also because they don't point to objects of the appropriate type
```

---

Better would be to use **smart pointers** that will take care of memory management for you. That is, when we use smart pointers we don't have to manually use `new` and `delete`.

---

Just so that you can see how to correct the current 2 mistakes you can refer to the below given modified example:

```
//this uses constructor initializer list 
Human(string p_name, int value): age(new int(value)), name(new std::string(p_name))
{
    
    cout <<"Name of Person is "<<*name <<" and age is "<<*age<<endl;
}
//destructor 
~Human()
{
    if (name != nullptr && age!=nullptr)
    {   //check that 
        delete name;
        delete age;
            
        cout<<"delete used successfully"<<endl;
                
     }
     else 
     {
        cout<<"delete not used"<<endl;
     }
            
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing out the concept of pointers

Comment: @RibhuSengupta [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is a list of [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that helped me while i was a beginner in C++.